# Me sale error cuando activo Mysql con Xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

**Ayúdenme Por favor, quise activar MySQL con xampp y me sale error,** ya lo desinstale y lo volví a instalar, pero me sigue apareciendo igual, Ayúdenme por favor, tengo que entregar un proyecto con phpMyAdmin y local host

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**TRANSCRIPCION DEL ERROR:**

```
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
03:33:54 a. m.  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: El mensaje de error detalla una serie de posibles causas que deberías revisar: 1. Puerto bloqueado (revisa en qué puerto estaría corriendo MySQL, que no haya otros programas corriendo en ese puerto y que el Firewall no lo esté bloqueando); 2. Faltan dependencias: revisa que no falten librerías necesarias para que MySQL se ejecute sin problemas; 3. Privilegios no apropiados: revisa los privilegios de usuarios (de MySQL o del sistema operativo en sí); 4. Un crash o apagado por otro método ... Puedes pulsar el botón Logs al lado de MySQL para más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

abre una temrinal y coloca el comando `netstat -ano | findstr :3306` para ver si no hay otros programas utilizando el puerto.

Te va a salir algo asi:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4568
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4568
```

para eliminar el proceso usa `taskkill /F /PID 4568`

con eso, intenta encenderlo de nuevo encenderlo.

También en configuración, puedes cambiar el puerto.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error